# How are primenumbers called that are written by two primenumbers like 53=5 and 3

Tags: prime-numbers, terminology, recreational-mathematics

How are primenumbers called that are made of 2 primenumbers?

Like 53=5 and 3, where 5 is prime and so is 3.

And is there a better method to check for such a trait than to

check for primeness and

disassemble 1113(as an example) into all possible substrings and check if those substrings are prime

So in the case 1113(which is NOT prime) check

1 and 113 -> 1 is not prime

11 and 13 -> 11 and 13 are both prime

111 and 3 -> 111 is not prime

Edit (expressed more mathematicly):

For some primenumber $N$ i want to find $p_1$ and $p_2$(where $p_i$ is a primenumber), such that $N=p_1\times 10^n + p_2$ for some natural $n$.

A general method for $k$ substrings is also appreciated.

Comment: So, effectively, do you wish to find numbers $N$ that are prime such that there exist two other primes $p_1$ and $p_2$ where $N=p_1\times 10^n + p_2$ for some natural $n$? We could probably generalise this for some $p_k$, although specificity is important prior to any furtherances.

Comment: @MrPie yes, those numbers $N$ are what I'm talking about, but I don't want to find them, I want to check for this trait. Doing this for $p_k$ would be neat. I edit my question so that it's more clear.

Comment: If you find the treats, you'll find them.

Comment: @MrPie Note your suggestion is the same as the OP's for the more basic case that is described (as I understand it, and I believe you do as well) only if you also add the condition that $p_2 \lt 10^n$.

Comment: The name for the operation is usually called "concatenation". This is what we get if we write the digits of two numbers together. Whether we get a prime this way, is usually unpredictiable, of course in some cases (digitsum for example) we know that the concatenation cannot be a prime.

Comment: I don't see why this was voted down, so I voted up. While I'm not sure this property is of wider interest, I don't think it is much sillier than so many other things that do get attention in maths. A lot of important mathematics probably started out as idle curiosity and 'stupid' questions.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n In fact, the questions with the best scores on this site are not necessarily the best questions. However, prime numbers apparently do not interest the majority of the mathematicians apart from special primes (like Mersenne primes), but others have done almost everything about those already. In particular concatenation is considered to be un "unnatural" operation , as I experienced with the ec-primes from Enzo Creti. Sometimes, I posted questions about numbers that I wanted to be factored. Sometimes, I received the factorization, sometimes not.

Comment: By the way, I also upvoted , although I am not sure what the author actually asks.

Comment: An example of a sexy prime pair with prime concatenation (That means, $p$ , $p+6$ and the concatenation of $p$ and $p+6$ are all proven primes) is : $$p=10^{200}+14586117$$

Comment: Why is the prime number $53$ meaningfully distinguishable from the prime number $89$? Their numerical representation is a happenstance of our choice of base $10$, not any mathematical property they possess or exhibit.

Comment: @KeithBackman With this argument, it would not be worth to think about left-truncatable or right-truncatable primes or deletable primes. All those concepts are base-dependent. Nevertheless they have been studied by some mathematicians. While a prime can be represented in every base, almost all articles about prime numbers represent them in base $10$, if it comes to concrete primes. I heard this argument with the dependence of the base also from other users, but it does not convince me. Of course, everyone can have the opinion that dealing with such numbers is "numerology".

Comment: @Peter Of course, what is worthwhile thinking about is often the choice of the person doing the thinking, and I do not wish to imply that thinking about truncatable primes (e.g.) is not worthwhile. But OP's question is "what are these numbers called?" Numbers that are called twin primes have properties that are independent of the base they are represented in; OP's primes do not. On a deeper level, questions such as OP's may in fact be more about properties base $10$ than about prime numbers. See continuation comment....

Comment: Take any other defined set of numbers, such as Fibonacci numbers, and represent them in a variety of bases, and you could ask questions about patterns that crop up in those representations, but they would not give you any information that was important in understanding Fibonacci numbers, just information about oddities that occur as a result of choice of base.

Comment: I sense a bit of Illuminati conspiracy here, just look at the numbers 5 and 3...